# Does the following product converge as $n$ approaches infinity?

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, riemann-zeta, products

Does the following product converge as $n$ approaches infinity?

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \prod_{c=2}^n{ \left( 1- \left( 1-\frac{1}{\zeta(c)} \right)^{2^\alpha} \right) }$$

Here $\zeta(c)$ is the Riemann zeta function, and $\alpha$ is a natural.

Comment: As it stands, you want to know $\lim \prod \frac{1}{\zeta(c)}$, correct?

Comment: @HarrySmit:  Oops, sorry - I forgot to add $2^\alpha$ into the formula.

Comment: Hint: since as $c\rightarrow \infty$ $\zeta(c)\sim 1-2^{-c}$ the parts of the  product behave as $\sim 1-2^{-2^a c}$. Since this converges to $1$ your sum converges

Comment: @tired: instead of $1 - 2^{2^\alpha/c}$ it should read $1 - 2^{-2^\alpha \cdot c}$, right?

Comment: @HarrySmit absolutly

Comment: @tired:  I'm thinking that $2^{-2^\alpha} = y$, and then we have the product would be approximately $(1-y)(1-y^2)(1-y^3)\cdots$.  According to Mathematice, this gives $\prod_{c=1}^b{ \left(1- y^c \right)}  =  \text{QPochhammer}[y,y,b]$.

Comment: Could always take the log of the thing to turn it into a sum.